# How can I jump to a different line in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a battleship game where the boats get placed randomly. I have 
 placed the largest boat in the table (6x1 in a row or colum  (chosen randomly)), 
 now I want to place the next boat in the table (4x1). For this I made a function
  that checks if the one of the 4 cells where I want to place the next boat is taken. 
 When this is taken I want to jump to "loop1:" to get a new randomly chosen 
 location for the boat. But the function won't work because of "loop1:" and 
"continue loop1;". This makes the function undefined. Could someone please 
 help me with this problem?

```js
function example() {
  loop1: 
  otherfunction();
  i = 1
  col = chosencol[0];
  row = chosencol[1];
  numb = parseInt(row, 10);
  x = 0;

  while (x <= 3) {
    numb = numb + i;
    cell = col + numb;
    if (getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(cell)).backgroundColor == color[0]) {
      alert("Cant be the same cell!");
      continue loop1;
    } else {
      return chosencol;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you can not have `countinue` outside of a loop.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to use (basically) `goto`?

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to do? I looked at your previous question but I'm still not sure.

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes.

Comment: btw, where is `x` incremented?

Comment: @ChrisG The "otherfunction()" picks a random set of cells in a colum from my table. If one of the cells has the color "color[0] I want it to go to "loop1:" and pick another set of cells.

Comment: @NinaScholz Woops forgot that my bad. But still doens't fix the problem.

Comment: So you have a table where some of the cells have a specific background color, and you want to pick a column where none of the cells has that color?

Comment: @ChrisG I have a table 10x10 where there are 6 cells who touch each other in a random colum (so 4 cells in that colum are still free) that are picked randomly ("A1-A6", "A2-A7"..."A5-A10)  that have a certain background color. I want to add some other cells with a different background color in the table. The new cells which are a set of 4 cells who touch each other get picked randomly (they can be placed in a row or colum somewhere in the table)  but they cannot overlap the already existing 6 cells.

Comment: please use local variables only, like parameters or locally defined once. then specify when you like to exit the function and how do you go on, preferably by using a recursive call (to get rid of the label) and by deleting the inner loop (this is important of another recursive call returns and is going on with the loop).

Comment: Right, so you're writing a Battleship Game basically? And you want to randomly place a bunch of ships in valid locations, I guess? Not sure which language you're coming from but JS is basically a functional language and you have to change your approach accordingly.

Comment: @ChrisG Yes. I'm doing this as a homework assignment and we have to do it in Javascript.

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/rz7gq5of/ The basic idea is to include picking a new spot in the while loop so you don't have to jump around

Answer (score -1):

The label should come immediately before the loop. There should not be any statement between a label name and associated loop.

Please refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label